# Is there a way to set configuration runtime options in code rather than in the config file?

Tags: c#, .net, web-config

I'm writing a .NET app and I want to set the `enforceFIPSPolicy` option to false, but I would like to do it in code rather than in the config file (app.config or web.config). Is this possible?

This is what it's supposed to look like in the config file:

```
<configuration>
    <runtime>
        <enforceFIPSPolicy enabled="false"/>
    </runtime>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 1):

No. `web/app.config` is loaded once at the application startup. Changing values of the file will have **no** effect.

If there is no such API to change the value in runtime, you are out of options I am afraid.

Comment: Can't you use the ConfigurationManager class? http://chiragrdarji.wordpress.com/2008/09/25/how-to-change-appconfig-file-run-time-using-c/

Comment: @alios, are you sure?  I know you can change an App/User setting and I think you can 'inject' a setting after startup, Saving would be optional.

Comment: @Henk, now you got me into doubting, before that I was sure - but I think it is correct. I remember I read that similar to the fact that loaded assemblies cannot be unloaded, config files are loaded at the start. **Any changes to file itself will be ignored after being loaded.** Having said that, the object structure that is loaded can be changed at runtime, e.g. adding connection strings, etc.

Comment: @Aliostad you are correct. The only way you can programmatically change this is by unloading / loading an AppDomain entirely.